# loop through string in a table and insert the data into an XML column in another table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table
`T1` containing two columns `str` and `num`

| str | num |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1, 2, 50, 60 |
| b | 5, 820, 601 |
| c | 9, 8, 52 |

...

I want to insert the data from `T1` into `T2` using PLSQL either with regular expression of `substr` and `instr`.
`T2` contains one XML column

output of `T2` XML column looks like:

```xml
<mycol>
  <name>a</name>
  <number>1</number>
  <number>2</number>
  <number>50</number>
  <number>60</number>
</mycol>
    
<mycol>
 <name>b</name>
 <number>5</number>
 <number>820</number>
 <number>601</number>
</mycol>
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can split `num` column by comma through use of hierarchical query along with regular expression functions, and then construct XML values by rendering returning columns from the first subquery through use of combination of some XML functions without need of PL/SQL such as

```sql
INSERT INTO t2
WITH t0 AS
(
  SELECT str AS "name", REGEXP_SUBSTR(num, '[^ ,]+', 1, level) AS "number"
    FROM t1
  CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(num, ',') + 1
         AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
         AND PRIOR str = str
)
SELECT XMLELEMENT("rows",
        XMLAGG(
                XMLELEMENT("mycol",
                           XMLFOREST("name"),
                           XMLAGG(
                                  XMLFOREST("number")
                                  )
                           )
              ) 
       )       
  FROM t0
 GROUP BY "name"
```

where `t2` table is assumed to be

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2( xml XMLType )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f246f8dd3561714093fdf33a518946b1)</kbd>